# SQL ALIAS not working in select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, alias

I have 2 select statement in which i want to use the result of this statement as ALIAS in Select query in order to get the result. But i am getting error in the last line of my query as `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`. I dont know what i am missing.
Here is my query:

```
Select(SELECT xt.id
FROM SOAP_MONITORING sm
CROSS JOIN XMLTable(XMLNAMESPACES (
      'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "soapenv",
      'http://service.soap.CDRator.com' as "ns",
      'http://core.data.soap.CDRator.com/xsd' as "ax2130",
      'http://webshop.result.service.soap.CDRator.com/xsd' as "ax2147"
    ),
    'for $i in /soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns:placeShopOrderResponse/ns:return/ax2147:subscriptions
      return $i/ax2130:id'
    passing XMLType(sm.RESPONSE_XML)
    columns "ID" number path '/')) AS xt,
    (SELECT xx.id
FROM SOAP_MONITORING sm
CROSS JOIN XMLTable(XMLNAMESPACES (
       'http://webshop.data.soap.CDRator.com/xsd' as "ns7"
    ),
    'for $i in //ns7:orderType return $i'
    passing XMLType(sm.REQUEST_XML)
    columns "ID" VARCHAR2(30) path '/')) AS xx
    FROM SOAP_MONITORING
where WEB_SERVICE_NAME='RatorWebShopService' and WEB_METHOD_NAME='placeShopOrder' and xx.id = 'NEW' ;
```

Comment: First question: have you validated all your sub selects work independently of that main query?

Comment: yes i have validated both my sql query and its working fine. Just i want use both this select query result as ALIAS and use it in my select statement. Because the both this select staement result belongs to single table. And i want to query the same table

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do subqueries, you can have two XMLTable clauses from the same `passing` target:

```
SELECT xt_res.id
FROM SOAP_MONITORING sm
CROSS JOIN XMLTable(XMLNAMESPACES (
      'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "soapenv",
      'http://service.soap.CDRator.com' as "ns",
      'http://core.data.soap.CDRator.com/xsd' as "ax2130",
      'http://webshop.result.service.soap.CDRator.com/xsd' as "ax2147"
    ),
    'for $i in /soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns:placeShopOrderResponse/ns:return/ax2147:subscriptions
      return $i/ax2130:id'
    passing XMLType(sm.RESPONSE_XML)
    columns "ID" number path '/') xt_res
CROSS JOIN XMLTable(XMLNAMESPACES (
       'http://webshop.data.soap.CDRator.com/xsd' as "ns7"
    ),
    'for $i in //ns7:orderType return $i'
    passing XMLType(sm.REQUEST_XML)
    columns "ORDER_TYPE" VARCHAR2(30) path '/') xt_req
where sm.WEB_SERVICE_NAME='RatorWebShopService'
and sm.WEB_METHOD_NAME='placeShopOrder'
and xt_req.order_type = 'NEW' ;  


                   ID
---------------------
   201501070917439804 
   201501070917439804
```

That's using the sample XML from your previous question, including the request from the rolled-back edit, both cleaned up to be valid...

---

Based on discussion that [continued in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69839/discussion-between-alex-poole-and-ajay), to get data from your `wf_workflow` table for the IDs this matches, you can either use a `join`:

```
SELECT wf.* from 
SOAP_MONITORING sm 
CROSS JOIN XMLTable(XMLNAMESPACES ( 
      'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "soapenv",
      'http://service.soap.CDRator.com' as "ns",
      'http://core.data.soap.CDRator.com/xsd' as "ax2130",
      'http://webshop.result.service.soap.CDRator.com/xsd' as "ax2147"
), 
'for $i in /soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns:placeShopOrderResponse/ns:return/ax2147:subscriptions 
return $i/ax2130:id' 
passing XMLType(sm.RESPONSE_XML) 
columns "ID" number path '/') xt_res 
CROSS JOIN XMLTable(XMLNAMESPACES ( 
       'http://webshop.data.soap.CDRator.com/xsd' as "ns7"
), 
'for $i in //ns7:orderType return $i' 
passing XMLType(sm.REQUEST_XML) 
columns "ORDER_TYPE" VARCHAR2(30) path '/') xt_req 
JOIN WF_WORKFLOW wf 
on wf.SUBSCRIPTION_ID = xt_res.id 
where sm.WEB_SERVICE_NAME='RatorWebShopService' 
and sm.WEB_METHOD_NAME='placeShopOrder' 
and xt_req.order_type = 'NEW'
and WF.NAME='INITIATE_MANDATE' 
and WF.STATUS_ID=0;
```

Or include the earlier query as an `in` clause; which might be easier to understand but is functionally equivalent (other than suppressing duplicates, which you said you won't have), and might have different performance to the `join` version:

```
SELECT wf.* 
from WF_WORKFLOW wf 
where wf.SUBSCRIPTION_ID in ( 
  select xt_res.id 
  from SOAP_MONITORING sm 
  CROSS JOIN XMLTable(XMLNAMESPACES ( 
        'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "soapenv",
        'http://service.soap.CDRator.com' as "ns",
        'http://core.data.soap.CDRator.com/xsd' as "ax2130",
        'http://webshop.result.service.soap.CDRator.com/xsd' as "ax2147"
  ), 
  'for $i in /soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns:placeShopOrderResponse/ns:return/ax2147:subscriptions 
  return $i/ax2130:id' 
  passing XMLType(sm.RESPONSE_XML) 
  columns "ID" number path '/') xt_res 
  CROSS JOIN XMLTable(XMLNAMESPACES ( 
         'http://webshop.data.soap.CDRator.com/xsd' as "ns7"
  ), 
  'for $i in //ns7:orderType return $i' 
  passing XMLType(sm.REQUEST_XML) 
  columns "ORDER_TYPE" VARCHAR2(30) path '/') xt_req 
  where sm.WEB_SERVICE_NAME='RatorWebShopService' 
  and sm.WEB_METHOD_NAME='placeShopOrder' 
  and xt_req.order_type = 'NEW'
) 
and WF.NAME='INITIATE_MANDATE' 
and WF.STATUS_ID=0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. Its working fine :). Now just a small question in order to use this ID and join with other table to get the result. How can we perform ? Do i need to take simply xt_req and use the result of this to join with other table ?

Comment: Didn't we cover this in the previous question? Yes, just add another join before the `where` clause, with the condition based on `xt_res.id`. (I just fixed the aliases, and changed the request column name to `order_type` to avoid confusion, including mine).

Comment: Thank you very much Alex :) You saved my life :) I spend complete day today to fix this issue.

Comment: Hello Alex i just found one issue to join the XT_RES.id with the other table. Because i want to compare the result of this complete query with WHERE clause as well with the ID from the other table. So if i dont use ALIAS and run the query as you said i will get wrong result right ? Because the above query you mentioned it will show the result for complete single table and i want to take this complete and compare it with the other table.

Comment: And thats why i thought to use ALIAS where i can store the result of this complete query and then use the result of this query to compare with the other table. Do you have any suggestion about this ?

Comment: The result with the ID i got i just want to use this ID result and perform the join with the ID from another table. So as to get the final output. The result with the WHERE condition in this query are valid for single table ony.

Comment: I have a table called WORKFLOW in which i have ID and want to compare and join the ID from the result of this complete query  what you have written . Do you know how can we do this ? I am trying with the ALIAS but no luck yet. It will be like Select ID from WORKFLOW WF join SOAP_MONITORING sm(complete result) on WF.ID = sm.ID

Comment: @ajay - why doesn't `join workflow w on w.id = xt_res.id where sm.WEB_...` work? I don't understand what you mean.`

Comment: can i update my query in question what i am trying? So you will understand what i want to say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69839/discussion-between-alex-poole-and-ajay).